# windows 10 Blocking Ubtuntu from being seen as bootable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows, alienware

so, this is kinda hard to exmaple...

**Simple**

Windows 10 blocks ubtuntu for being seen as a bootable in my bios

**More info**

Alienware 17 R4 is the computer
Came with 128 flash SSD (dell/aleinware's windows10) with 1TB HD
i added another flash SSD to it that has ubtuntu on it. was bootable and every thing worked great( ubtuntu ran VERY well). sadly windows10 was so unstable i took out both the 128GB flash SSD and the 1T HD and put in a 500GB normal SSD and put my own windows 10 on. it runs SO much better. but now my labtop wont see ubuntu unless i take out the 500GB SSD with windows 10...

**What i Tried to do...**

updated all software with 10, flashed the bios. swap the flash SSD in the other slot... checked incase i didnt put in right some how... nothing worked. i even reinstalled ubtuntu and windows 10 again...nope...

**The Odd...**

if i hit F12 to see what is bootable it used to label under Legacy options hardrive ( that was ubtuntu). then under UEFI Options it listed the flash 128 ( dell's Windows 10). now it only list hardrive under legacy.. thats windows 10 that on the normal SSD thats a fresh clean install with my windows 10 usb... its like it forgot that window 10 is UEFI....

Testing some thing odd....

**Thank you**
for reading my horrible grammar and all v.v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's Worth I Saw a post saying the proper method was to install windows 10 then return to boot, now boot Linux install and grub should fix your boot section. Windows is so demanding in how it boots.

[here](http://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-mint-18-alongside-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot-uefi-mode/) is the post I followed hope it helps someone in there dual boot process.

Comment: thank you ^^ wish i came here sooner :3 god i love the linux community ^^

Answer (score 0):

OK so i dont fully understand new way UEFI n windows 10 work i guess. but if i put my labtop into UEFI boot. and install windows 10 it works with ubuntu again. so i guess if u make Windows 10 be installed for uefi mode it fixed it fully. i hope this helps some one down the line. maybe this labtop can only handle one non uefi bootable OS?, if anyone can answer what happen that be awsome! :l

**The Fix**

install windows 10 while bios is in UEFI mode. then take put it back to leacy or leave it for linux to work.

Comment: Regarding UEFI, it uses a special partition on your disks (the EFI System Partition, ESP for short), to tell the BIOS what systems are bootable. The advantage for you is that OSes don't interfere with one another's bootloaders so when installing Windows 10, the worst it would to is set Windows first. You could simply move Ubuntu to be first again in the preferred order and it would work as expected without having to reinstall grub.

Comment: so odd to me to have it where the bios has to need UEFI patition on the drive then just let it worked how it used to be. i though UEFI was some thing where the OS has power over the BIOs. Mmmm this is good to know but odd...

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem,  and in fact whenever Windows 10 runs their update software, even for third party installs, it will make my separate Linux hard drive disappear from the boot menu in the bios.

To fix things I usually have to go into my BIOS twice, after rebooting twice (and hitting the DEL key).  I can find my hard drive device in the list of peripherals and then eventually it will be listed again as a boot device.  Once that happens I am able to make it the only boot disk my machine will boot off of.